# Presence of underestimation bias in earnings predictions

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, forecasting, model-evaluation, finance

I am working on a financial data that entails forecasted revenue a company generates over a fiscal quarter and the actual revenue for that quarter.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': ["Q3'16", "Q1'17", "Q2'17","Q3'17"],'Predicted M1':[1000,1026,1023,1024],'Actual Earnings':[1010,1030,1020,1026]})
```

Every month throughout the quarter I generate a new forecast for what revenue will be at the end of the quarter.

**A little background on the data**. These are consensus earnings predictions/estimate for a quarter(around 17 data points). If a company beats these predictions they enjoy a positive share price change. This gives an incentive for analyst/manager to under predict those earnings. Hence majority of predictions are underestimated.

**My question is this: How can I prove/show presence of such biases in the forecast.**

Comment: You want to check whether your forecasts are biased? That is if you have under/over-forecast-ed in the past? Is this all the data that you have?

Comment: Yes. To check if they are underpredicted on purpose instead of being random @user2974951

Comment: What do you mean `on purpose`? Are these forecasts from a model or from people? Also, it's going to be very hard to determine this based on 4 points.

Comment: I only have 5 years data, about 17 data points. Forecasts are generated from a model.